# Replace some numeric value after a pattern in a string of txt in R (grep?)

Tags: r, string, text, gsub

I have several txt files that are input file for a model, I need to change some of the model parameters in order to conduct some experiments. However, there are many parameters and changing them by hand is somewhat time consuming. I thought about using readLines() and {grep} in R to search and replace the parameter values but not very successful, hope someone could help me. Thank you.

The file has lines like this:

```
Bubbling Pressure 1          = 0.3389 .4423 .4118
Field Capacity 1             = 0.35  0.38  0.37
Wilting Point 1              = 0.13  0.14  0.13
Bulk Density 1               = 750. 1400. 1500.
Vertical Conductivity 1      = 2.904e-06  3.63e-05  3.63e-05

.....

Bubbling Pressure 3          = 0.2044 0.2876 0.2876
Field Capacity 3             = 0.31  0.33  0.33
Wilting Point 3              = 0.13  0.14  0.14
Bulk Density 3               = 750. 1400. 1500.
Vertical Conductivity 3      = 3.16e-06  3.95e-05  3.95e-05

...
```

I want to double all vertical conductivity parameters...But I am not sure how to isolate those numbers in scientific notation (such as "3.16e-06").

Is there a way to isolate each one of the number in lines that contain the pattern "vertical conductivity"

```
Vertical Conductivity 3      = 3.16e-06  3.95e-05  3.95e-05
```

And then double each one of the numbers?

```
Vertical Conductivity 3      = 6.32e-06  7.90e-05  7.90e-05
```

I have manage to use grep to isolate each line of text that contains the pattern "Vertical Conductivity" but I am not sure how to get the numerical values out...

Thanks,
Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this easily with `gsubfn` without changing the original structure and modify it into something the OP may or may not wanted.

Here, we are reading the dataset using `readLines`, get the index of 'lines' where it has 'Vertical Conductivity' substring with `grepl` ('i1').  Then, use `gsubfn` to replace those values to the double of that.

```
library(gsubfn)
i1 <- grepl("Vertical Conductivity", lines)
lines[i1] <- gsubfn("[0-9.]+e[-+][0-9]+", ~format(as.numeric(x)*2, 
                                           scientific = TRUE), lines[i1]) 
lines
#[1] "Bubbling Pressure 1          = 0.3389 .4423 .4118"           
#[2] "Field Capacity 1             = 0.35  0.38  0.37"             
#[3] "Wilting Point 1              = 0.13  0.14  0.13"             
#[4] "Bulk Density 1               = 750. 1400. 1500."             
#[5] "Vertical Conductivity 1      = 5.808e-06  7.26e-05  7.26e-05"
#[6] "Bubbling Pressure 3          = 0.2044 0.2876 0.2876"         
#[7] "Field Capacity 3             = 0.31  0.33  0.33"             
#[8] "Wilting Point 3              = 0.13  0.14  0.14"             
#[9] "Bulk Density 3               = 750. 1400. 1500."             
#[10] "Vertical Conductivity 3      = 6.32e-06  7.9e-05  7.9e-05"
```

#### data

```
lines <- trimws(readLines(textConnection(
          'Bubbling Pressure 1          = 0.3389 .4423 .4118
           Field Capacity 1             = 0.35  0.38  0.37
           Wilting Point 1              = 0.13  0.14  0.13
           Bulk Density 1               = 750. 1400. 1500.
           Vertical Conductivity 1      = 2.904e-06  3.63e-05  3.63e-05
           Bubbling Pressure 3          = 0.2044 0.2876 0.2876
           Field Capacity 3             = 0.31  0.33  0.33
           Wilting Point 3              = 0.13  0.14  0.14
           Bulk Density 3               = 750. 1400. 1500.
           Vertical Conductivity 3      = 3.16e-06  3.95e-05  3.95e-05')))
```

We can also directly read this from file

```
lines <- readLines("yourfile.txt")
```

Comment: This works great for parameters like the vertical conductivity that has scientific format. Many thanks!
However, when I try to change other parameters like (say wilting point) which use decimal numbers, the parameter numbering also get changed as the model input value:

gsubfn("[0-9.]+", ~format(as.numeric(x)*0.5, 
                      scientific = FALSE), input.file[i])

 Wilting Point 1.5              = 0.065  0.07  0.07

Is there a way to change only the values AFTER the "=" sign?

Thanks!

Comment: never mind...I used strsplit() and solved the second question myself :) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your data is not tidy, so the first step is to munge it into a useful form. Hadley Wickham's `tidyr` package has the tools you need to do so, and ties in nicely with his `dplyr` package which will let you double the variable you care about.

```
# read in data
df <- read.csv(text = 'Bubbling Pressure 1          = 0.3389 .4423 .4118
               Field Capacity 1             = 0.35  0.38  0.37
               Wilting Point 1              = 0.13  0.14  0.13
               Bulk Density 1               = 750. 1400. 1500.
               Vertical Conductivity 1      = 2.904e-06  3.63e-05  3.63e-05
               Bubbling Pressure 3          = 0.2044 0.2876 0.2876
               Field Capacity 3             = 0.31  0.33  0.33
               Wilting Point 3              = 0.13  0.14  0.14
               Bulk Density 3               = 750. 1400. 1500.
               Vertical Conductivity 3      = 3.16e-06  3.95e-05  3.95e-05', 
    sep = '=', header = FALSE, strip = TRUE)
```

Now to tidy:

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

       # separate variable from identifier
df %>% separate(V1, c('var', 'var_id'), sep = ' (?=.$)', convert = TRUE) %>% 
    # separate values for each variable
    separate(V2, 1:3, sep = ' +', convert = TRUE) %>% 
    # melt values to long form so there's one observation per row
    gather(val_id, val, -var:-var_id, convert = TRUE) %>% 
    # spread variables so each column is one variable
    spread(var, val) %>%
    # use data.frame to make names without spaces
    data.frame() %>%
    # use dplyr::mutate to double vertical conductivity as desired
    mutate(Vertical.Conductivity = Vertical.Conductivity * 2)

#   var_id val_id Bubbling.Pressure Bulk.Density Field.Capacity Vertical.Conductivity
# 1      1      1            0.3389          750           0.35             5.808e-06
# 2      1      2            0.4423         1400           0.38             7.260e-05
# 3      1      3            0.4118         1500           0.37             7.260e-05
# 4      3      1            0.2044          750           0.31             6.320e-06
# 5      3      2            0.2876         1400           0.33             7.900e-05
# 6      3      3            0.2876         1500           0.33             7.900e-05
#   Wilting.Point
# 1          0.13
# 2          0.14
# 3          0.13
# 4          0.13
# 5          0.14
# 6          0.14
```